# Split words in java

Tags: java, regex

I would like to split a text into single words using java.

**SalesCost for State , testing , "28 Oct, 2011 00:00:00" , 12**

Expect result:

1.SalesCost for State
2.testing
3."28 Oct, 2011 00:00:00"
4.12

Comma separated split is not proper.

Is there any other solutions to this?
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

-spk-

Comment: Get a CSV parsing library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053761/what-is-a-good-csv-java-utility

Comment: "/W+" will do that ..include this in regex..

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy seems like you end up with the same problem. It should match ", " in the date, no?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to parse a CSV file? Looks like that. Anyway you can give [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) a try. You can also use it to parse comma separated String and define escape character like the quotation mark.

Answer (score 3):

`String.split()` uses regular expressions. So you can use negative look-ahead to do this.

Try something like this:

`split("(?!\\"),(?!\\")");`

I have not tried this specific regex but play a little bit with it and refer to API doc. In the end of the day this should work.

BUT it seems that you just want to parse CSV format. So, I'd recommend you to use CSV parser. For example this one: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi Alex, shall you explain this regex.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like CSV. Use http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/

You can set column and row delimiter and text quoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you can always expect the space before commas separating fields, you could always add that to your delimiter to avoid splitting on the comma in the date. Not as flexible by any means but might be a much quicker fix if it would be safe to use on the data.